# Interconnectivity

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, graph-theory

As I was walking through my university's mathematics department, I came across a poster pinned to the notice board. Underneath, it simply said 'In memory'. However, I could not connect the poster to the person it celebrated; because there was no name in sight! I'm sure you can help me, though...

[image: monument]

***Well? Whom does it commemorate?***

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Each of the four diagrams with letters

> can *almost* be rearranged to have the form at the top

but in each case

> one edge of the graph -- one connection between letters -- is missing.

These are, respectively,

> D-I, J-K, S-T, and R-A

so this is a memorial to

> Edsger Dijkstra.

I expect it was constructed using graphs because

> some of Dijkstra's most famous work involves algorithms operating on graphs. (Most importantly, his shortest-path-finding algorithm.)

Comment: Fantastic detective work =)

Comment: Thanks. I liked this puzzle a lot. Short but sweet.